# How can I sync mail older than two weeks on my iOS 4.1 device?

Tags: data-synchronization, email, exchange-activesync

In the settings for my exchange account I only see options for syncing up to two weeks back, not more. Is there a way I could sync mail that is more than two weeks old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Exchange Administrator has used the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) on the server to adjust how many weeks of mail you are allowed to sync. It is not possible to override this value on the phone itself without jailbraking.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is set by the Exchange administrator, it can be up to one month.

[image]